# parsing & displaying images in gridview

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a xml containing few images and i need to display the images in a grid view.
I'm able to parse the image urls, but while displaying the grid view only the last image of the xml is being displayed. I have the code below.

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
   if(nil != qualifiedName){
           elementName = qualifiedName;
   }
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"images"]) {
           self.ixml = [[ImageObj alloc]init];
   } 
   else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"] )


   {
           self.currentElement = [NSMutableString string];
   } else {
           self.currentElement = nil;
   }        
}




 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
   if(nil != qName){
           elementName = qName;
   }
   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]){
   self.ixml.imageName=self.currentElement;
           NSLog(@"data %@",self.currentElement);
   }
 else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"images"])    {
           [[self imagerssItems] addObject:self.ixml];
   NSLog(@"self ixml %@",self.ixml);
    NSLog(@"self  %@",imagerssItems);
   }
}
```

all the urls are being displayed in log in `NSLog(@"data %@",self.currentElement);` but in the following lines

`NSLog(@"self ixml %@",self.ixml);
     NSLog(@"self  %@",imagerssItems);`

it shows only one element is being set.

Am I missing out something here? Guidance will help.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

we have the xml format as below-

```
<images>
<image>link here</image>
<image>link here</image>
<image>link here</image>
</images>
```

Is the parsing procedure right?

Answer (score 0):

use this delegate for storing in array.

```
//Receive string of current element
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
   {


   }
```

and then Print it in  "didEndElement" delegate